# Fluid flowing into small pores

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, surface-tension

I have some open porous foams with pore sizes ranging from 50-100nm. I want to flow water into this structure but even at 30 atmospheres it would NOT go in. I am looking for a way to calculate the pressure needed for the water to be pushed in.

The foam is a polymer with contact angle of 75 degrees. I tried using the [porosimetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porosimetry) equation based on Washburn's equation but the result comes out to about 7.4 atmospheres, which doesn't match my experiment. I took SEM images and am sure that the pore size is correct. I know that the equation should be applied to "non wetting" liquids which is probably the issue.

Does anyone know another model/equation I can use? I tried looking at lots of papers and cannot find the answer. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Did you try using a surfactant? Would your application allow for a chemical modification of the surface?

Comment: Did you try Googol kPa? According to my calculations, a pressure of Googol kPa would be sufficient.

Comment: Did you try liquid helium at 2.17K or below? If that won't go through, nothing will.

Comment: I just want an equation that can predict the pressure necessary for the water to go inside the porous structure. I am not trying to change this required pressure by using chemicals, I simply want to calculate what that pressure is.

Comment: It appears the the pores are in the same scale as the molecules of water.  If this is the case, the amount of "force" required to "push" it through may be related to the force required to "break" the hydrogen-oxygen bond. In which case you would end up "passing" hydrogen and oxygen, instead of water.